# NSURL Connection sendAsynchronousRequest How to save the response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, completionhandler

```
.h
@property (strong) NSString *reply;
```

I have the following method:

```
.m
@synthesize reply;

- (void)send
 {
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[self request] 
                 queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] 
                 completionHandler:
                        ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)       
                        {
                            if (error)
                            {
                                //NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                [self setReply: [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[error localizedDescription]]];
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                //NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
                                [self setReply: [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
                            } 
                        }];

}
```

Now, I have tried to return a value from the block/handler, but apparently this is not possible ( or I haven't figured out the syntax yet ).

I have tried to set a local variable to get the value of the reply (Data) but it produces errors.

The only way that errors were not produced is by using a class property. But when I try to read the value of [self reply] it is null, which makes me think that it is never set.

I understand that the sendAsync function is threaded and asynchronous, so is that the reason that the value of [self reply] is null, while when I use a sendSynchronousRequest, I always get a reply ???

What am I doing wrong, and how can I return a value from within the completionHandler ???

Edit#1: It appears to me that Im doing something very wrong. I was tracing into the code, and when I used the synchronous send, everything worked fine. Using the asynchronous one, the actual call to sendAsynchronousRequest was never executed, making me think that the thread is not being invoked, and hence the empty value.

Edit#2: I have found a way around this, by adding the following:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[self request] 
                 queue:[NSOperationQueue alloc] init
                 completionHandler:
                        ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)       
                        {
                            if (error)
                            {
                                //NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                [self setReply: [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[error localizedDescription]]];
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                //NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
                                [self setReply: [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
                            } 
                        }];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 2]];
```

However, I am not entirely sure I understand how it works. I imagine that RunLoop tells the async operation to run for 2 seconds ( I can verify because when setting the date interval to a low value, I get a null response, due to testing with a live server ). What I do not understand, is when I just tell the RunLoop to run, it keeps blocking everything forever, as if the current thread never terminated.

Comment: I don't understand the problem/question. Why can't you return a value from the block completion function ? What does the setReply function do? Show us the code

Comment: Set a breakpoint to see if data is valid or null.

You're on the right track and this seems valid but you might not be getting information back that you can use.

Comment: The block is specified as having a void return type, so the block itself cannot return a value - but why do you need to return a value? I'm guessing your setReply function simply is simply a setter for an instance variable? In this case, you shouldn't need to return anything from the block, as the response will be captured when you setReply. What is the error that is produced when you use a local variable to capture the value of data? You should just be able to set a breakpoint to view the data. Also, I would add check the response code you are receiving.

Comment: I basically want a value ( a string ) back from the asyncRequest. I have tried searching for hours on how to return a value from the nested function, but to no avail. Problem is that the "reply" is never set, and remains null for some reason.

Comment: The NSLog, does print out the value/response, however when I try to set the local property, it is not set.

Comment: Like Jacob said, set a breakpoint at your calls to setReply: and check the string you are passing to the setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a month later, I found the solution to my problem:

```
    NSURLConnection* _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[self request] delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    self.port = [NSPort port];                                                                                                       
    self.runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];                                                                                       
    [self.runloop addPort:self.port forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_connection scheduleInRunLoop:self.runloop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_connection start];
    while (self.finished != YES ) {
        [self.runloop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1]];                                                                    
    }
    [self.runloop removePort:[self port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_connection unscheduleFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

This did the trick for me. Bear in mind I had to properly implement NSConnection's delegate methods (didReceiveResponse,didReceiveData,didFailWithError,connectionDidFinishLoading).
However it is now working asynchronously, does not freeze the UI, and has proper error reporting. 
Hope it may help someone stuck at the same issue

Comment: If you're down-voting - at least take the time to say why

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of that runUntilDate and try using [NSOperationQueue mainQueue], see if that changes anything.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[self request] 
             queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
             completionHandler:
                    ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)...
```

Comment: I've tried that, did not make a difference. It was actually the way I first tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the __block keyword for the declaration of your property reply

```
@property (strong) __block NSString *reply;
```

This keyword makes your property writable from inside a block.

**EDIT**

Proposal for a method that blocks the main thread until a response is received or until the request times out:

```
//this block is used to define a waiting condition
typedef BOOL (^ CheckBlock)();

- (BOOL)waitUntilBlockTrue:(CheckBlock)theBlock orTimeout:(int)timeout {
    NSDate *waitingStartPoint = [NSDate date];
    BOOL stillNeedToWait = YES;
    while (stillNeedToWait && theBlock()) {
        stillNeedToWait = ([waitingStartPoint timeIntervalSinceNow]*(-1.0)) < timeout;
    }
    return stillNeedToWait;
}
```

For your example you would call this method with:

```
[self waitUntilBlockTrue:^{
        //returns YES as long as the method should block
        return (BOOL)(self.reply == nil);
    } orTimeout:10];
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't make a difference. My guess is that the main thread terminates faster than the async send operation finishes. Thanks for telling me this though, its good to know.

Comment: Well if you are using this async call and you want the main thread to wait for the response you have to block the main thread. I had this problem while I was writing tests with SenTestCase. Check out the method I am using to block the main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and add the code. Unfortunatelly, I can't get it to build, as I'm getting an error of passing the wrong type of parameter to the block function ( Invalid block pointer conversion from unsigned char BOOL to (BOOL)^() ). More over, it seems to me that we're going at this the same way using different approaches. I've added the async send on the main queue, and then told it to runLoop for 10 seconds ( my timeout ). Isn't that what you are doing, with the exception that what you have done will stop blocking once a value is returned ?

Comment: Oh I didn't check the syntax. Added a cast to BOOL so the compiler knows the return type of the block. I am not sure but it could be that in your case runUntilDate does not block. You could check that by butting an NSLog before and after the runUntilDate call and check if messages in the console really are 2 seconds appart.

The documentation of runUntilDate states: "If no input sources or timers are attached to the run loop, this method exits immediately" This could be the case because you are specifically creating a separate NSOperationQueue.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks, it now builds properly, but somehow, I'm still not getting a value in the reply. Im probably missing something or not understanding how GCD works. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Never use __block on properties. Use wrefs to self and set the property, [wself setFoo:bas]